# Convert an object :Color to a double[3]

Tags: arrays, javafx, colors

Do you know if it's possible to convert an object `:Color` to an array of `double` containing its R, its G and its B, in one line ?

It would be very practical for me because I wrote a photo-retouching function which has to be independent of the implementation's constraints (example : the language used). So this function needs a `double[]` as parameter and not a `:Color`.

For the moment, the function has three `double` as parameters but it's less practical.

PS : I don't want to just create myself a `double[]` and fill it with `getRed`, etc. : I really want to create and fill this array in one instruction.

Answer (score 0):

> PS : I don't want to just create myself a double[] and fill it with
>   getRed, etc. : I really want to create and fill this array in one
>   instruction.

Since it's a very easy task, what stops you from writing your own method that does it? Example implementation:

```
private double[] getColors(Color c) {
   return new double[]{c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue()};
}
```

Usage:

```
Color c = Color.RED;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getColors(c)));
```

And the result:

> [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]